# Youtube title should be shown on embedded videos

Tags: video, youtube, embed

On this webpage: [www.motorsamling.com/videos.asp](http://motorsamling.com/videos.asp) I have dynamically embedded a lot of video clips from Youtube that are shown four at a time on each tab.

The title of each is supposed to be the title that the Youtube video has in the top of the video player for each video - in other words, the title that I have given the video in Youtube will be shown in the top of the video when the video is embedded onto another page.

But for some reason this Youtube-title is missing at several of the videos and only shown at some.

Does anyone know this problem or at least an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it seems the "showinfo" parameter is getting confused.  It's supposed to default to "1".  Maybe if you set it to "1" explicitly it will work.  Although I wasn't able to reproduce your problem in this example, it does show how to use the parameter:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
object, embed, iframe {
  max-height: 325px !important;
  max-width: 400px !important;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <object width="960" height="745">
      <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/9OnIBGR1KRY?fs=1&hl=da_DK&rel=0&hd=1&showinfo=0">
      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
      <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/9OnIBGR1KRY?fs=1&hl=da_DK&rel=0&hd=1&showinfo=0" 
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="960" height="745">

    </object>
    <object width="960" height="745">
      <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/wQpJ_-H1qTc?fs=1&hl=da_DK&rel=0&hd=1">
      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
      <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/wQpJ_-H1qTc?fs=1&hl=da_DK&rel=0&hd=1" 
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="960" height="745">

    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally I found a possible solution. I will try this one and report back about the results. Good day.